# Counterexample sought to show that squared Hellinger distance doesnt satisfy the triangle inequality

Tags: probability, functions, metric-spaces

I read in a paper that the squared Hellinger distance between two densities $f$ and $g$

$$H^2(f,g)=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{g(x)}\right)^2 dx$$

is not a metric. I wonder if there is a nice counterexample showing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to create examples: You would like to contradict the triangle inequality, as the other properties of a metric are satisfied, so you are looking for densities $f,g,h$ such that $2(H^2(f,g) + H^2(g,h) < 2H^2(f,h)$, or equivalently by definition
$$\int f + g - 2\sqrt{fg} + \int g + h - 2\sqrt{gh} < \int f + h - 2 \sqrt{fh},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\int 2g - 2(\sqrt{fg} + \sqrt{gh}) < \int -2\sqrt{fh}.$$
Now you can construct examples using any densities $f,g,h$ satisfying the following:
$$fh = 0$$ 
$$\sqrt{fg} + \sqrt{gh} > g.$$

For instance consider the domain $[0,1]$ and the densities 
$$g(x) \equiv 1 $$
$$f(x) = 2 \mathcal I_{[0,1/2]}(x)$$
$$h(x) = 2 \mathcal I_{[1/2,1]}(x).$$

$\mathcal I_A$ denotes the indicator function of a set $A$, being $1$ at points of $A$ and $0$ otherwise, so $\sqrt{fg} + \sqrt{gh} \equiv \sqrt{2} > 1 \equiv g$.

Comment: I see but I need an example when both densities have support on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. I do not see any obvious easy example, but you can construct examples out of the above one. Consider densities $f_n, g_n, h_n$ supported on $\mathbb R$ which converge to $f,g,h$ respectively. Then for big $n$ things will work.